# Fazendo um OCR sem dependências em PHP

Tags: php, ocr

Eu tenho um [projeto](http://tudo.marta.preuss.nom.br/tumblr) onde as pessoas fazem agendamento de frases para o Tumblr. Hoje funciona a partir do Kindle e eu já estou vendo os arquivos do Kobo. Mas hoje venho pedir ajuda para a terceira parte: gostaria de adicionar um **leitor OCR**, de forma que a pessoa pudesse subir uma foto, o leitor extraísse a frase e a pessoa pudesse adicionar na fila de publicação de frases.

Eu sou bem iniciante em PHP e sofro um pouco, e pesquisando não tive muito sucesso. Achei um plugin que identifica apenas letra por letra ou um plugin que precisa rodar um `exec`, o que não é interessante porque a pessoa pode não ter o programa instalado e por questões óbvias de segurança.

Eu deveria tentar fazer isso com outra linguagem? Estou apostando no PHP primeiro porque tenho uma base, depois porque o projeto está feito em php, minha hospedagem é php e porque sei que ele tem uma biblioteca para lidar com imagens, então supus que o OCR não estaria tão distante.

Vocês têm algum plugin ou tutorial para indicar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Caso você possua a possibilidade de instalação em seu servidor, [Tesseract](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) é uma engine OCR opensource disponibilizada pela Google. Ela possui um [wrapper para PHP](https://github.com/thiagoalessio/tesseract-ocr-for-php).

Caso contrário, você pode tentar *webservices* como o [Google Docs OCR](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#uploading_documents_using_optical_character_recognition_ocr).

Comment: Desculpe, mas aí eu não teria de instalar o TesseractOCR no meu servidor? Ou chamar com exec? Eu não tenho permissões para nenhum dos dois. Ou eu só copio a pasta "api" do TesseractOCR no meu servidor?

Comment: @Marta Este é um fator bastante limitante. Você pode tentar webservices como o Google Docs OCR: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#uploading_documents_using_optical_character_recognition_ocr

Comment: Obrigada @OnoSendai. Eu gosto da minha hospedagem mas a dificuldade em instalar coisas realmente tem me limitado muito.

Comment: @Marta, uma sugestão, porque não contrata uma VPS barata (Linode, Digital Ocean ou AWS e etc). Implementa um serviço que usar o Tesseract nela (Como um Web Service) e usa a partir de sua hospedagem atual?

Comment: Dei uma olhada e acho que vai ser o caso mesmo. Obrigada.

Comment: @Marta boa sorte - e sinta-se à vontade no caso de alguma dúvida.

Answer (score 3):

Humm sem ter um módulo de processamento de imagem para o PHP instalado no servidor você vai sofrer um pouco, dá uma olhada se no lugar que você hospeda tem o módulo [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php), crie um `phpinfo();` só para checar o que tem de módulos instalado para o seu PHP. Se o `ImageMagick` tiver disponível as coisas melhoram mas não ficam menos complicadas.

Eu só posso te guiar com os passos necessários, desconheço se existe algo pronto, o desafio parece ser mais interessante do que simplesmente copiar algo de alguém, você vai precisar de algum conhecimento matemático, álgebra linear e se quiser um algoritmo realmente perto da perfeição vai precisar de redes neurais.

Vamos começar pelo método mais básico possível:

- crie vetores com os padrões de todas as letras e números, você vai precisar recortar cada letra e número, extraia os pixels de cada um, use o ImageMagick se estiver disponível, armazene da maneira que achar conveniente (txt, mysql).
- Agora você já tem a base para comparação, você vai querer comparar frases/textos/palavras com os padrões extraídos, mais uma vez use se disponível o ImageMagick para recortar cada letra de seus textos, computacionalmente falando você vai comparando horizontalmente cada pixel até encontrar o inicio e fim de cada letra, estamos falando de algo básico aqui, então 99% dos textos estão em preto com fundo branco, então caminhe até o pixel branco acabar marque a posição e caminhe até o pixel preto acabar marque a posição, isso vai te falar onde recortar cada letra ou número (inicio e fim).
- Perfeito recortou a letra do texto, agora extraia os pixels dela, assim como no primeiro passo feito para construir seu banco.
- Agora compare o que foi extraído do texto com o seu banco de dados, em álgebra linear tem um conceito chamado `espaço linear` neste caso teremos quais pixels aparecem com mais frequência, é uma maneira simples que pode ser usada para mensural qual é a letra mais parecida.
- Monte cada palavra baseado neste rank (quanto maior o cosseno retornado pelo espaço linear melhor)

Bom ai está uma maneira básica de construir um OCR com suas próprias mãos, sem depender de módulos de terceiros(exceto o ImageMagick, usado aqui para recortar e extrair pixels).

Comment: Whoa que bela resposta! Obrigada! Não tenho conhecimento atualmente para tanto, mas um dia ainda tento construir algo nesse sentido :)

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar a classe [php OCR](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2874-PHP-Recognize-text-objects-in-graphical-images.html) que faz o aprendizado e reconhecimento de texto em imagens totalmente em PHP, pelo que não precisa instalar nada no seu servidor.

Comment: Eu tentei usar essa classe mas não me serve. "It can recognize text in monochrome graphical images after a training phase.", ou seja, eu preciso "treinar" o algorítimo para reconhecer letra por letra. Não funciona com um texto longo. Mas obrigada pela dica :)

Comment: @Marta está havendo um mal-entendido. O treinamento é sempre necessário porque a solução usa redes neurais. Agora depois de treinar, a classe vai reconhecer letras mesmo com tipo diferente das usadas no treino. Não importa se o texto é longo ou curto. Quanto mais treinar, melhor vai funcionar a classe. Agora não espere nenhuma solução que funciona 100% em todos casos, pois isso não existe.

Comment: Sim, já trabalhei antes com OCR no PC e sei que é comum ter pequenos erros como j, i, l, 1 por exemplo. Mas eu não tinha entendido como eu ia treinar nessa classe todas as letras possíveis, com todas as fontes possíveis, para fazer o que eu necessito. Como foi dito em outra resposta, eu teria de comparar os vetores das letras com os caracteres em si é para isso essa classe ajudaria; mas no meu caso, usar um webservice é o mais apropriado. Obrigada pela ajuda :)

Comment: Então, aí é que está, não precisa de treinar com todas as fontes possíveis porque não é assim que funcionam os algoritmos de redes neurais. Se você já resolveu seu problema com um Webservice, tudo bem, mas só para você entender esse Webservice muito provavelmente também foi treinado da mesma forma. Ou seja vai ter uma solução idêntica, apenas dependendo de um Webservice que por vezes pode estar indisponível quando você precisa.

Comment: Concordo com você. Acho que preciso estudar isso melhor.