# Processamento de Imagem? Dúvida sobre o tema e usabilidade

Tags: php, java, c, c++, processamento-de-imagens

Fala galera tudo bem ? Tenho uma dúvida se é esse mesmo nome do tema **Processamento de Imagem**
Não sei se vocês ja deram uma olhada existem alguns aplicativos que trazem uma proposta como essa.

Existe um de tradução de palavras, que ao colocar a câmera do celular em algum texto ele traduz para a lingua que você escolher.

Minha dúvida é. Como se chama essa "mágica", qual linguagem é utilizada para isso? Existe alguma biblioteca que auxilie ao desenvolvimento ? 
Até pensei que existiria uma I.A para fazer esse processamento e tal, detectar objetos, textos essas coisas. Podem me dar uma luz sobre isso ? 
Obrigado.

Comment: Não sei se isto está no escopo do site, mas acho que quer computação cognitiva https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_computing.

Comment: Obrigado, vou dar uma olhada.

Comment: Primeiro, você faz interpretar o texto a partir de uma imagem; depois faz tentar identificar o idioma a partir do texto e, finalmente, fazer a tradução. Faça passo a passo que ficará bem mais simples.

Comment: Quando o moderador expert diz não ter certeza, é porque a pergunta é boa. +1

Comment: [OpenCV (Open Source Computer Vision Library)](https://opencv.org/)

Comment: @maneiro acho que ele quer se chama realidade aumentada

Comment: @ramaral OpenCV pode ser usado para desenvolver apenas uma parte da brincadeira

Answer (score 1):

É um campo novo quem vem ganhando espaço chamado de [Realidade Aumentada](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Realidade_aumentada):

> Azuma define a realidade aumentada como um sistema que:
>
> - combina elementos virtuais com o ambiente real;
> - é interativa e tem processamento em tempo real;
> - é concebida em três dimensões.

Com o grande poder de processamento e memória crescendo exponencialmente em dispositivos móveis iterações entre ambiente real e virtual por câmera/áudio é uma realidade, vide `Pokemon Go`, claro é um game utilizando o poder de processamento do seu smart phone para construir em tempo real combinações de elementos reais(imagens da sua câmera) com elementos virtuais("bichinhos" que parecem estar na sua frente quando você olha as imagens geradas pela câmera).

A Realidade Aumentada é um conceito, a linguagem pra fazer isso pode ser qualquer uma, claro no caso de Pokemon Go, e aplicativos para celulares Android, a maioria é escrita em `java` combinando códigos `C/C++` com o `JNI` (Java Native Interface).

O Exemplo que você deu sobre o APP que consegue traduzir palavras e frases em tempo real apontando o celular possui alguns passos, parece mágica, mas não é, se você se dedicar você pode construir um protótipo desse tipo de algoritmo usando o seu smart phone, anote a receita:

- Você precisa aprender sobre processamento de imagens
- Álgebra linear(cálculo básico sobre dimensões x,y,z)
- Aprenda linguagem `C` para escrever os códigos que identifique OCR(Optical
  Character Recognition), simmmm é claro que você vai precisar
  segmentar cada palavra/frase/letra, você só vai conseguir isso
  desenvolvendo um OCR que terá a função de extrair as letras de uma imagem/camera e retornar em modo texto, essa é uma parte complexa do código, geralmente é
  escrito em `C` para ganhar desempenho, você pode usar uma biblioteca
  chamada `OpenCV`, ela possui muitas funções prontas para trabalhar com
  processamento de imagens, quer saber em detalhes como construir um
  `OCR` ? os passos estão nesta minha [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/109436/o-que-%C3%A9-necess%C3%A1rio-para-ocr-android/118799#118799) ou [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/29835/7503), se precisar de algo mais prático escrevi um código com algum conceito sobre como separar cada letra usando python [aqui](https://ederwander.wordpress.com/2010/02/08/principios-para-identificacao-de-caracteres-em-python/)
- Aprenda linguagem Java(android)
- Aprenda como integrar códigos `C` com Java usando `JNI`
- Treinar uma grande base de dados utilizando todo o alfabeto com
  diferente tipos de fonte (você quer que o seu algoritmo seja robusto ?
  quer que ele consiga ler e identificar a maior quantidade de fontes
  né? Arial/italic/times new roman/etc, etc, etc)
- Dicionário para traduzir cada palavra convertida em texto ( ou seja
  você vai basicamente precisar de um tradutor de palavras/frases)
- Após você ter capturado o texto e traduzido, você agora vai precisar
  substituir o texto original com o novo texto, você sabe quais são as
  coordenadas no plano que a sua câmera está capturando, certamente
  você deve ter guardado as posições x,y,z no momento que segmentou a
  palavra/frase utilizando o `OCR` agora vc só tem que sobrepor a frase
  original pela frase traduzida... Pronto lol

Claro que é complexo rsrs, mas os passos estão ai ...

Answer (score 0):

Complementando a resposta do ederwander, acho que o que você está procurando mesmo é algo relacionado a OCR, e uma ferramenta amplamente utilizada é o [tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract)

A questão do treinamento nem sempre será um problema pois já existem bons treinamentos disponíveis online inclusive para pt-br, quanto a linguagem também, fique tranquilo pois existem wrappers para várias, como c# e python por exemplo.

Comment: um OCR de terceiro não vai funcionar, como ele vai saber exatamente a coordenada do texto para poder substituir pela tradução em tempo real ? os OCRs tradicionais só capturam imagens e convertem o texto da imagem para o modo texto, ele precisa mais do que só fazer isso, ele precisa saber onde na imagem o texto está para poder sobrescrever pelo texto traduzido   ...